# how can I find out if an answer worked, even though the OP didn't mark a best answer?

Tags: discussion, comments, new-users

I don't have enough points yet to make a comment, and I don't have the answer to the question I'm viewing. People have answered, but none of the answers were selected as the best answer. I can't tell if the person ever found an answer to his question. I want to make a comment and ask him, but I can't. Is there any other way to find out if the answer that was provided worked?

Or, can I somehow contact the person who answered his question so I can get further clarification on the answer he gave?

Answer (score 3):

Users who ask the question can accept an answer, but that doesn't mean the accepted answer is the best answer in absolute. It just means there is an answer that helped the OP more than other answers did. You can first check the accepted answer to see if it works for you too, but that answer could not help you, partially help you, or take you to right direction to find the solution in your case.
Without an accepted answer, I would look at the answer with the higher score first, and then the other ones.

There isn't a way to contact the users who answered a question for a simple reason: The site's focus is questions and answers, not the users.

Answer (score 0):

As kiamlaluno stated, there isn't a contact form built into SE sites, but there is a public profile that has a website field and a short bio section. You can reach it by clicking the avatar image or user name next to each question or comment. If they've filled it out that should give you some clue on how to contact them.